# Resize working ext4 partition

Tags: 14.04, gparted

I would like to resize `ext4` partition in order to make place for windows storage. Unfortunately I can't resize it - gparted will not allow me to do that:

[image]

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats because you run gparted on the running system. You should boot your pc with gparted live cd/usb: 
http://gparted.org/livecd.php

Comment: I tried this with Ubuntu live CD, but still can't resize it

Comment: did you unmount `/dev/sda`?